# Telegraf node.js отправить данные при ответе

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Есть код:

```js
bot.command('search_sale', (ctx) => {
        ctx.reply('Выберите категорию: ', {
            reply_markup: {
                keyboard: [
                    [{text:"Сантехника и отопление", callback_data: "search_sale"},
                    {text:"Инструменты", callback_data: "order_material"}],

                    [{text:"Лакокрасочная продукция", callback_data: "search_sale"},
                    {text:"Отделочные и облицовочные материалы", callback_data: "order_material"}],
               ]
            }
        })
        
    })
```

Можно ли как-то передать какое-нибудь значение вместе с callback_data? Не говорю, что так правильно использовать, но как пример, чтобы было понимание

```js
bot.command('search_sale', (ctx) => {
        ctx.reply('Выберите категорию: ', {
            reply_markup: {
                keyboard: [
                    [{text:"Сантехника и отопление", callback_data: { callback: "order_material", "someonevalue": "value"}},
                    {text:"Инструменты", callback_data: { callback: "order_material", "someonevalue": "value"}}],

                    [{text:"Лакокрасочная продукция", callback_data: { callback: "order_material", "someonevalue": "value"}},
                    {text:"Отделочные и облицовочные материалы", callback_data: { callback: "order_material", "someonevalue": "value"}}],
               ]
            }
        })
        
    })
```

На названия callback функций не смотрите, всего лишь пример. Дело в том, что по сути, все кнопки будут выдавать одну и ту же инфу, но надо, чтобы было понятно с какой именно кнопки перешли на новый callback.

Comment: сделайте каждой кнопке свой callback. или попробуйте посылать в callback_data json (сериализованный объект).

Comment: В том и дело, что callback‘ов много, хотелось бы их сделать динамичными

Answer (score 0):

```js
inline_keyboard: [
                    [{text:"Сантехника и отопление", callback_data: "ss_ch_r 1"},
                    {text:"Инструменты", callback_data: "ss_ch_r 2"}]
                    ]
```

Вставляем в callback_data необходимые данные. Считаем потом из `ctx.update.callback_query.data`